# execute some function after rivets.js binding finishes

Tags: rivets.js

I'm kinda new to rivets and I don't fully understand it so I came upon which seems to be a pretty basic thing to do, but I couldn't do it.

I'm trying to execute some jQuery that only runs AFTER rivets finished binding everything? (it is a $().each that enables click event on each line created after rivets binds a list to a rv-each li element)

It isn't working, but if I try to manually call the function after the pages finished loading and after rivets finished binding (on the browser console), then everything works great.

Comment: You got it worked but you want to understand the concept or do you still have some problem??

Comment: I got it to work by doing a nasty trick: I binded rivets to a input hidden a started a setInterval to check that input value every 100ms and after it has value, execute my script and clear the interval. It looks ugly, but works.

Comment: Nice trick to make it work.. But i'm curious to know why it is not working..

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong. In fact, I'm not sure how to do it at all. How could I know that the binding "is over"? It seems to me that it is an assynchronous task. Even if I call something after the .bind() it executes before the values are where they should be.

Comment: Do you have any web service call to fetch the model or collection?

Comment: I dont think there is anything built into rivets to do this - see   https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/issues/337

Comment: @Priya no, it is just plain MVC.

Comment: @Symeon I guess I will stick with my "trick" using setInterval

Comment: I'm using rivets with backbone. This had never happened to me. So i'm just wondering how its working for me..

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code you want to execute after rivets binding is done inside a [0 timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful), so that it is pushed to the bottom of the callstack and will be executed after the existing tasks are completed.

---

```js
var bigArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
  /* ADJUST THIS untill you see the difference
                                       WARNING: Keep it under control
                                    */
  bigArr.push({
    count: i
  });
}
rivets.bind($("div"), { // bind rivets
  arr: bigArr
});


setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("rivets done it's thing!"); // executed when binding is done
}, 0);

console.log("Rivets..? Who!"); // executed before elements are rendered
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rivets/0.7.1/rivets.bundled.min.js"></script>
<div rv-each-item="arr">{item.count}</div>
```